# How to iterate over next data structure?

Tags: algorithm, dart, parsing

I have app config. I need to iterate over it's sections. The problem that format is not "standard". For example for next config I need to extract three sections that I need too extract:

```
[
 [
  a: 1
  b: ["foo" "bar" "baz"]
 ]

 [
  c: 2
  d: "some value"
  e: ["mike" "piter"]
 ]

 [
  f: 3
  g: "some another value"
 ]
]
```

And print one by one:

```
 [
  a: 1
  b: ["foo" "bar" "baz"]
 ]
```

then:

```
 [
  c: 2
  d: "some value"
  e: ["mike" "piter"]
 ]
```

...

I tried to solve this task with regExp, but very encountered an error because nested elements have brackets too.

Here is my code:

```
void main() {
  
String str = '''[
[
 a: 1
 b: ["foo" "bar" "baz"]
]

[
 c: 2
 d: "some value"
 e: ["mike" "piter"]
]

[
 f: 3
 g: "some another value"
]

]''';
  
final myRegexp = RegExp(r'\[[^\][]*]');
  
 Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = myRegexp.allMatches(str);
  
  for (var el in matches) {
    var blk = el.group(0);
    if(blk != null) {
     print(blk);  
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: "The problem that format is not "standard"" Instead of writing yet another parser for yet another non-standard format, use a standard format. Problem solved.

Comment: I can’t its red-lang blocks.

Comment: No idea what that is or why it's a requirement.

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov Is it possible to write some program in Red which exports your configuration to e.g. JSON or another more commonly used format for data exchange? I have tried reading the specification for Red Blocks and it does not seem that it can just easily be parsed using a Regular Expression so you would need to write a parser for that format. So an easier way to handle this would be to have a Red lang program convert the data structure to something Dart (or a package on pub.dev) already understands.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some tiny parser that can extract section from red-block. It have a lot of limitation, but work with basic case from example. Here is full code:

```
void main() {
  
String str = '''[
[
 a: 1
 b: ["foo" "bar" "baz"]
]

[
 c: 2
 d: "some value"
 e: ["mike" "piter"]
]

[
 f: 3
 g: "some another value"
]

]''';

List stack = [];
List pairsList = [];
int start_pos = 0;
int end_pos = 0;
List singlePairs = [];
  
bool isNewLine = false;
int index = 0;
str.split('').forEach((ch) {
  if(ch == '[') {
    start_pos = index;
    if(stack.length == 1) {
      singlePairs.add(start_pos);
    }
    stack.add(1);
      
  }
  if(ch == ']') {
    end_pos = index;
    stack.removeLast();
    if(stack.length == 1) {
      singlePairs.add(++end_pos); // to correct substringing
      pairsList.add(singlePairs);
      singlePairs = [];
    }
            
  } 
  index++;
});

  

  getConfigSection(int sectionNumber) {
    if(sectionNumber == 0) {print("Config number should be >= 1, but not 0"); return;}
    if(sectionNumber > pairsList.length) {
      print("Config have only ${pairsList.length} sections. You specified: $sectionNumber");
    } else {
      sectionNumber--; // to make order of config start from 1, not from 0
      int start = pairsList[sectionNumber][0];
      int end = pairsList[sectionNumber][1];
      String singleSection = str.substring(start, end);
      print(singleSection);

    }

  }
  
  getConfigSection(1);
}
```

output:

```
[
 a: 1
 b: ["foo" "bar" "baz"]
]
```